# Should I combine graph with RDB?

Tags: database, neo4j

I'm wondering wether it's a good practice to combine both Neo4j and RDB.

More specifically, here are two cases:

1. Keeping track of nodes changes history (like Git).
2. Logging all the user activity: if an user fallows another and than unfollow - I wan't to keep track of both the events.

For these two, should I use Neo4j and RDB or only Neo4j?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst generally not a bad practice, I would start simple and only use Neo4j in your case. If you find the need to deploy another kind of database on the side, you can always do it later.

For keeping track of node changes, there are a number of strategies. An excellent survey of those is here: http://iansrobinson.com/2014/05/13/time-based-versioned-graphs/

For logging user activity, I would create a FOLLOW relationship first and give it a created timestamp. When the unfollow event happens, just give the same relationship a deleted timestamp.